# Изменить версию python в win 11

Tags: python

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как изменить версию питона в винде по умолчанию. В командной строке 3.8, и все модули устанавливаются в нее. В IDE 3.11. Как сделать, чтобы 3.11 была по умолчанию в cmd?

Comment: во-первых, не советую сразу лезть на 3.11. 3.8 вполне себе годный питон. во-вторых, если приспичило, попробуйте виртуальное окружение.

Comment: С виртуальным окружением попробую. Но просто хочется знать способ как поменять текущую версию в винде.

Comment: там посмотрите PATH сначала, если там увидите, то поправьте.